# Extract residuals only for two observations

Tags: r

Below is my code for a regression analysis.

```
Reg <- lm(hgc94~father_hgc+edex79, data=NLSY_education)
summary(Reg)
```

After this process, how could I calculate/report only the first two respondent's residual among 200 respondents?

Comment: are you referring to the result of `summary(Reg)$coef` ?

Comment: Need to know if there are missing data. Need to know which cases are the desired ones. The data your seek will be in `Reg`. Look at the values section for ?lm

Comment: It worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to handle this. The first would be to use brute force and calculate predictions with `newdata=<subset of the two obs>` as an argument to `predict.lm`, and the second would be to examine the `$residuals` values in the `Reg`-object. If the first two observations are `NLSY_education[1:2,]`, then it might be as simple as:

```
 #See ?lm, Values section
 Reg$residuals[1:2]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. It worked really well.